# How to Make a Bluetooth Dongle Discoverable at ALL times?

Tags: android, bluetooth, dongle, discoverability

I'm a bit unsure of where to post this question, so if anyone thinks I'm in the wrong place and knows where I should be posting it could you please point me in the right direction? Much Appreciated :)

Moving on to my question,
I am working on a project that allows location tracking of a person inside a building by placing usb bluetooth dongles around some rooms (in laptops or usb plugs etc) and saving their information in a database. Using an Android phone I then wanted to be able to discover the devices as I walk around with it on me and then calculate a location using the closest 3.

The problem I'm having is that my Android device will not discover the dongles that I have plugged into various laptops unless I set them to "Receive a file" i.e. discoverable (I assume). Does anyone know if it's possible to set them to be discoverable at all times or make it a default setting so I can plug it into sockets?
If this is not an option, is it possible to find the closest dongles while they are not set to discoverable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may require an native application to do this. There is no setting for this in the base OS. But to my knowledge you should be able to call the discovery process through the Bluetooth APIs.